# Encoding in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, encoding, aes, hmac

I'm very new in programming with Javascript and stuck in encoding my data.

I have done this as per need in my Android App, but could not able to do the same in JavaScript for my web portal.

The code which I'm using in Android App:

```
 public void encryptdata(byte[] data) {
    Encrypter encrypter = new Encrypter(); 
    HashGenerator hashGenerator = new HashGenerator();
    try {
        byte[] e = encrypter.generateSessionKey();
        byte[] encryptedData = encrypter.encryptUsingSessionKey(e, data);
        byte[] hmac = hashGenerator.generateSha256Hash(data);
        byte[] encryptedHmacBytes = encrypter.encryptUsingSessionKey(e, hmac);
        this.encodedSessionKey = encodeBase64(e);
        this.encodedHmac = encodeBase64(encryptedHmacBytes);
        this.encodedData = encodeBase64(encryptedData);
        } catch (Exception var6) {
        var6.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(var6);
    }
}
```

Encrypter.java

```
class Encrypter {
private static final String JCE_PROVIDER = "BC";
private static final int SYMMETRIC_KEY_SIZE = 256;

Encrypter() {
}

public byte[] generateSessionKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException {
    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES", "BC");
    kgen.init(256);
    SecretKey key = kgen.generateKey();
    byte[] symmKey = key.getEncoded();
    return symmKey;
}

public byte[] encryptUsingSessionKey(byte[] skey, byte[] data) throws InvalidCipherTextException {
    PaddedBufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new AESEngine(), new PKCS7Padding());
    cipher.init(true, new KeyParameter(skey));
    int outputSize = cipher.getOutputSize(data.length);
    byte[] tempOP = new byte[outputSize];
    int processLen = cipher.processBytes(data, 0, data.length, tempOP, 0);
    int outputLen = cipher.doFinal(tempOP, processLen);
    byte[] result = new byte[processLen + outputLen];
    System.arraycopy(tempOP, 0, result, 0, result.length);
    return result;
}

static {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
}
}
```

HashGenerator.java

```
class HashGenerator {
public HashGenerator() {
}

public byte[] generateSha256Hash(byte[] message) {
    String var2 = "SHA-256";
    String var3 = "BC";
    byte[] var4 = null;

    try {
        MessageDigest var7 = MessageDigest.getInstance(var2, var3);
        var7.reset();
        var4 = var7.digest(message);
    } catch (Exception var6) {
        var6.printStackTrace();
    }

    return var4;
}
}
```

These piece of code encoding the data and giving me HMAC as per my need, but I am not able to do same with JavaScript.

Can anyone give any reference or code on for JavaScript client.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So you did not try anything in javascript, not even the basics?

Comment: documentation for [SubtleCrypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for down-voting the question, may be a not great question, but here I done it myself

```
this.doEncryption = function (data) {
var key = btoa(this.generateRandomString());
var Encryptionkey = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key);
var encryptedPid = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data,Encryptionkey,{ mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7});
var sha256 = CryptoJS.SHA256(data);
var encryptedHmac = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(sha256,Encryptionkey,{ mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7});
return {
    encryptionKey : key,
    encryptedPid : encryptedPid.toString(),
    encryptedHmac : encryptedHmac.toString()
};
```